# Assign multiple values from object to single item in listview using array adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, jodatime

I have an `Appointment` object which contains several fields inside it; subject, start time, end time, etc etc.

I'm trying to get a list of these objects to appear in a listview. I have a list item layout xml file which contains 4 `TextView` objects; start time, end time, subject and person name. The layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblSubject"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblSubject"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSubject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Location"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblSubject"
        android:text="Customer"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblLocation"
        android:background="#333333" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I'd like to do is get this list of appointments (contained in an `ArrayList<Appointment>`) to show up on my listview.

Here is a cut-down version of my appointment object:

```
public class Appointment {

    ///////////////////////////
    // If isFreeTime is true, this object becomes a dummy appointment.
    // It then gets used as a 'free time' entry on the diary screen.
    boolean isFreeTime = false;
    ///////////////////////////

    UUID appointmentId;
    UUID appointmentTypeId;
    UUID customerId;
    DateTime startDateTime;
    DateTime endDateTime;

    String subject;

    // lots of other variables here

    ////////////////////////////////////
    // Constructors
    public Appointment(){
        if (this.appointmentId == null)
            this.appointmentId = UUID.randomUUID();
    }
    public Appointment(UUID id){
        if (id == null)
            this.appointmentId = UUID.randomUUID();
        else this.appointmentId = id;
    }
    public Appointment(String id){
        if (id == null)
            this.appointmentId = UUID.randomUUID();
        else this.appointmentId = UUID.fromString(id);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////

    public UUID getID(){
        return this.appointmentId;
    }

    public void setID(UUID appointmentId){
        this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
    }

    public boolean save()
    {
        // Saves this object to db
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasFreeTimeBefore(Appointment appt2)
    {
        if (this.endDateTime.toDate().before(appt2.startDateTime.toDate()))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public ContentValues getValues()
    {
        // Puts all local variables into a ContentValues object for db storage.
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
     return this.subject;
    }
}
```

My code so far:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter cAdapter;
DiaryAdapter dAdapter;
DateTime currentDate;
ListView diary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);
    diary = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstAppts);

    currentDate = new DateTime();
    populateDiaryNew(currentDate);
}

private void populateDiaryNew(DateTime dt) {
    currentDate = dt;
    ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
    Cursor cursor = Db.Functions.getAppointmentList(dt);
    if (cursor == null)
        return;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Appointment appt = Db.Functions.getAppointment(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        appointments.add(appt);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    ListIterator<Appointment> iter = appointments.listIterator();
    DateTime lastEndTime = new DateTime();
    int count = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        lastEndTime = iter.next().endDateTime;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            if (iter.next().startDateTime.isAfter(lastEndTime))
            {
                Appointment freeAppt = new Appointment();
                freeAppt.isFreeTime = true;
                freeAppt.subject = "Free slot";
                freeAppt.startDateTime = lastEndTime;
                freeAppt.endDateTime = iter.next().startDateTime;
                appointments.add(freeAppt);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Appointment> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Appointment>(this, R.layout.appointment_info, R.id.lblSubject, appointments);
    diary.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);     
}
```

The problem is that the `ArrayAdapter` only seems to adapt one field to one view - but I need to adapt 4 different fields (from one `Appointment` object) to 4 different TextViews all in a *single listview item*. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to override the getView method in your ArrayAdapter to manually inflate each row to how you want it.  By default, ArrayAdapter just calls toString() on your object to display.

Similar to this: [Custom ArrayAdapter](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/)

Code example:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView v1;
    TextView v2;
    TextView v3;
    TextView v4;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Appointment temp = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) { //inflate convertView and populate viewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, parent, false);
        viewHolder.v1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTime);
        viewHolder.v2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSubject);
        viewHolder.v3= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
        viewHolder.v4= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblCustomer);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder); //set the tag
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); //re-use the ViewHolder to     save calls to findViewById
    }
    viewHolder.v1.setText(temp.getText1());
    viewHolder.v2.setText(temp.getText2());
    viewHolder.v3.setText(temp.getText3());
    viewHolder.v4.setText(temp.getText4());
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide array list object `appointments` to ArrayAdapter -

```
 arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointments);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Appointment>{

ArrayList<Contact> items;

LayoutInflater mInflater ; 

Context context;

int layoutResourceId; 

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Appointment> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);

    this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;

    this.items = items;

    this.context=context;
}.......
```

Then override getView() and  inflate views for List items  and then set appointment values from ArrayList object items from specified position

Answer (score 0):

Consider SimpleCursor Adapter instead of ArrayAdapter,
in which you can pass custom view and bind data to it.
Or make custom ArrayAdapter by extending ArrayAdapter